# Alpaca trade api error: 'REST' object has no attribute 'get_barset'

Tags: api, finance, quantitative-finance, quandl, alpacajs

I use ALPACA paper markets. I'm trying to get stock data from ALPACA markets to put into a dataframe, and running into an error.

**AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)  in  11 # Get 1 year's worth of historical data for Tesla and Coca-Cola 12 # YOUR CODE HERE! ---> 13 df_ticker = alpaca.get_barset( 14 ticker, 15 timeframe, AttributeError: 'REST' object has no attribute 'get_barset'**

Imports

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import alpaca_trade_api as tradeapi
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv('.env')    # loading my environment variables.
```

1. Import my API keys from the loaded environment variables.

```
alpaca_api_key = os.getenv("ALPACA_API_KEY")
alpaca_secret_key = os.getenv("ALPACA_SECRET_KEY")
```

2. Create the alpaca REST object.

```
alpaca = tradeapi.REST(
    alpaca_api_key,
    alpaca_secret_key,
    api_version="v2"
)
```

3. Define stock data variables to use to fetch historic data. I am getting the past year of closing prices for each day.

```
ticker = [list of stocks]
timeframe = "1D"    # 1-days worth of closing prices.
start_date = pd.Timestamp("2021-07-26", tz="America/New_York").isoformat()
end_date = pd.Timestamp("2022-07-26", tz="America/New_York").isoformat()
```

4. Create a dataframe with the fetched stock data. This is where it fails.

```
df_ticker = alpaca.get_barset(
    ticker,                           
    timeframe,                   # 1-day closing prices.
    start = start_date,   
    end = end_date,
    limit = 1000                 # put a limit that way there's not too mucb data returned and screws up program.
).df                             # format as a dataframe
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like get_barset() is part of the V1 API for alpaca, you need to use the get_bars() method with V2, or else specify the API V1 when creating the REST object.